# How to capture a click on a specific leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I think the question says it all. 
I am using leaflet. I am loading three layers onto the map.

However I can't find a way to know on which layer I clicked after clicking on the map.
Basically because there is no event handler set on layers, only onto the map.

I also tried to add the layers into a feature group and add an on click event to this feature group. However clicking on the map does not result in any event / response.

This is what I did in the featureGroup:

```
addWaterNameLayers: function() {

    var knownWaters = L.tileLayer.wms(getGeoServer('wms', geoEnviroment), {
        layers: this.wmsLayers.known.name,
        format: 'image/png',
        opacity: 0,
        styles: 'cursor: pointer',
        transparent: true,
        attribution: ""
    });//.addTo(this.mapInfo);

    var unknownWaters = L.tileLayer.wms(getGeoServer('wms', geoEnviroment), {
        layers: this.wmsLayers.unknown.name,
        format: 'image/png',
        opacity: 0.3,
        styles: '',
        transparent: true,
        attribution: ""
    });

    L.FeatureGroup(knownWaters, unknownWaters).on('click', function(event) {
       console.log('click');
       this.handleClick(event);
    },this);

    //this part will work on mapclick, so on featuregroup it should work?
    //when clicking on the map
    /*
    this.mapInfo.on('click', function(event) {
        this.handleClick(event);
    }, this);
    */

},
```

in the code above you can see the click event on te map as well... that one works.
on the featuregroup it doesn't.

Also when I change the code for the featureGroup to these it will not work either:

```
    var featGr = L.FeatureGroup(knownWaters, unknownWaters).on('click', function(event) {
       this.handleClick(event);
    },this);


    var featGr = L.FeatureGroup(knownWaters, unknownWaters);
    featGr.on('click', function(event) {
       this.handleClick(event);
    },this);
```

adding the featureGroup to the layer will also do nothing...

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I have same problem...

Comment: with WMS layers you need to iterate, but it has been a while back so can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

Put your layers in [L.FeatureGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup). L.FeatureGroup is an extension of [L.LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) which adds events. It also supports the clickevent so that's exactly what your are looking for. Check the documentation: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup

Comment: thnx but I did put it in a feature group, however I cannot capture the click. I will try again just to be sure.

Comment: I didn't realize you were talking about (wms) tilelayers. This will ofcourse never work with tilelayers, since they're overlapping imagery. You would never get another result than the current visible layer that's on top.

Comment: I was affraid of that ;) So nothing else to do than to iterate over the layers?

Answer (score 1):

`event.layer` is layer data

```
event.originalEvent.path[0]
```

is element you clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
 L.FeatureGroup(knownWaters, unknownWaters).on('click', function(event: LeafletMouseEvent) {
   console.log('click');console.log(event.layer) //event.layer is the layer clicked
   this.handleClick(event);
},this);
```

The Code attaches a Click event handler on the FeatureGroup Layer which contains the "knownWaters" and "unknownWaters" layers.
Clicking on the map( featuregroup) will pass a leafletMouseEvent which contains the layer within the layergroup that was clicked

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.